# StateFlow/LiveData not updating after back pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-navigation, kotlin-flow

I have a problem with the flow of data inside my application.

I've got two Fragments, both of which modify the same data, and both of them go through a centralized Repository class in order to do so.

My problem is that if I navigate from Fragment A >> Fragment B, have Fragment B modify the data (say, delete a piece) and then *back press/gesture* myself back into Fragment A, Fragment A will still show the state of the data it was before the initial navigation, and data modification.  I should add that, if I navigate explicitly back into the previous fragment, everything works.  It is the back action specifically that isn't acting as I would've expected otherwise.

The way both Fragments manage the given data is through a Repository class.  This repository uses a Kotlin `SharedFlow` to communicate with the respective Fragment's ViewModels, and then the ViewModel tunnels the given data using `LiveData` into the Fragment.

Here's some code.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: ViewModelA by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            it?.let {
                binding.fragmentInt.text = it.toString()
            }
        }
        binding.fragmentInt.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(
                FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB()
            )
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class ViewModelA @Inject constructor(
    private val intRepository: IntRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state: MutableLiveData<Int?> = MutableLiveData(null)
    val state: LiveData<Int?> = _state

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            intRepository.observeScreenState().collect {
                _state.value = it
            }
        }
        intRepository.updateScreenState(1)
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentB : Fragment(R.layout.fragment) {

    private val viewModel: ViewModelB by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            it?.let {
                binding.fragmentInt.text = it.toString()
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class ViewModelB @Inject constructor(
    private val intRepository: IntRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state: MutableLiveData<Int?> = MutableLiveData(null)
    val state: LiveData<Int?> = _state

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            intRepository.observeScreenState().collect {
                _state.value = it
            }
        }
        intRepository.updateScreenState(6)
    }
}

class IntRepository @Inject constructor() {

    private val screenStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null)

    fun observeScreenState(): Flow<Int?> = screenStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun updateScreenState(value: Int) {
        screenStateFlow.value = value
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** After extensive testing and the support of a dummy app, I've noticed that the problem seems to be the use of the Hilt library.  Without it, my flows work exactly as I would expect, but it seems that the addition of the DI library is halting the `viewModelScope` from collecting the data that is supposed to be observing.  I've updated the code to reflect the state of the dummy app that lead me to this conclusion.

No clear answer on how -- or why -- Hilt is doing this so far.

Comment: Is the repository defined as singleton? Did you try to debug this? For example, does _state.value in ViewModel A get updated or not?

Comment: I've certainly tried debugging this @VítKapitola, and _state.value inside the ViewModel never gets an update.  The Repository is being injected by Hilt (something I omitted here, apologies) so I assume the init block is not being called more than once?  I would kind of expect the collection to resume once the ViewModel gets brought back into the foreground, but perhaps my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Your repository isn't a singleton. That would also cause your problem.

Comment: Yup!  @Tenfour04 I have now realized that, about 10 minutes ago.  

@VítKapitola since your comment vaguely lead me to the eventual answer of adding a simple -- yet missable -- `@Singleton` annotation into my Repository, I'll gladly grant you the right answer if you want to post that!

Comment: @Ivan Garza glad to know, that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your SharedFlow in the repository is using the default `replay` parameter of 0. This means when your fragments go off screen and come back on, they will get a new ViewModel that creates a new StateFlow that is collecting over from scratch from the repository SharedFlow, but the SharedFlow won’t pass any values that were emitted from before.

Change your SharedFlow to have a `replay` of one, or change it into a StateFlow.

Also, look up the `shareIn` and `stateIn` functions. They will clean up your code quite a bit. For example, this does what the code you posted above does while also avoiding unnecessary updating while the view mode is out of scope.

```
// ViewModel A
...
private val state = screenStateRepository.observeScreenStateFlow()
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), ScreenStateState())
```

Comment: While it is not reflected in my question, I have tried using either a `StateFlow`, or a `SharedFlow` with a replay # -- up to 10 -- but the collection still doesn't happen when I pop the back stack from Fragment B.  I've vaguely started looking into the functions you've recommended, but I think you're either missing a parameter, or have an extra one.  Also, it seems like you're missing a launch somewhere, as AS is complainig about that too.

Comment: I've updated the description and code to better reflect my progress.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the second parameter, which is required.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to listen to your variable again when you go to a different screen and come back again

```
init {
   viewModelScope.launch {
       screenStateRepository.observeScreenStateFlow().collect {
           _state.value = it
       }
   }
}
```

You should call the code gateway I specified in fragment inside onViewCreate as below.

```
fun testt() {
viewModelScope.launch {
       screenStateRepository.observeScreenStateFlow().collect {
           _state.value = it
       }
   }
}
```

on Fragment;

```
override onViewCreated(.....) {
    viewModel.test()
}
```

Comment: I know there's quite a few ways to work around my problem, but that doesn't fix the root cause: the `viewModelScope` is not collecting the changing data as it is supposed to.  Do you happen to know how to keep collection inside the ini{} block and have it work?  Or alternatively, do you have any documentation stating that collecting a flow in the init block is not the way to go?  I would prefer to save myself these repeating calls inside the `onResume()` of my Fragments every time something happens.

Comment: On a second note @Sahin, this solution did not work either.  Popping up the backstack does not make a subsequent call to the `onViewCreated(..)` function of the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

As it was highlighted in the comments and my progress updates, it turns out that Hilt was creating alternative versions of my repository due to the fact that the `@Singleton` annotation was missing.

Since I'm fairly new to the Hilt library, this completely went over my head.  But after hours of debugging, and narrowing down the culprit to the injected dependencies, a quick re-read to Dagger's Hilt docs -- plus the help of some insightful comments here -- lead me to the simple answer of adding the required annotation, as to ensure the right behavior of my Repository.

Answer (score -1):

```
Since your code is quite abstract, I don't understand it very well. You should write it out clearly because dealing with the code in the flow is quite complicated, easy to misunderstand. I have never used SharedFlow, only StateFlow. Here are the things I usually do, you can refer to, hope to help you:
//Repository
     suspend fun setFrameCustom(frame: String) {
         context.dataStore.edit {
             it[FRAME_CUSTOM_DEFAULT] = frame
         }
     }

     val frameDefault: Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data.catch { exception ->
         if (exception is IOException) {
             emit(emptyPreferences())
         } else {
             emit(emptyPreferences())
             throw exception
         }
     }.map { preference ->
         preference[FRAME_CUSTOM_DEFAULT] ?: ""
     }

     companion object {
         val FRAME_CUSTOM_DEFAULT = stringPreferencesKey("FRAME_CUSTOM_DEFAULT")
     }
// Model A
     val frameDefaultFlow = repository.frameDefault
//Model REMOVED
     fun setTemplateDefault(template: String) {
         viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
             repository.setFrameCustom(template)
         }
     }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if my code is hard to read, your answer is too!  Mind fixing the code blocks and being more explicit on what does what?  I don't follow.

Comment: I've updated the description and code to better reflect my progress.